# How to access XML file when running a Junit with association of property file?

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, junit

I am developing a spring + maven project. And in some classes I am reading XML file in my project. Path for the XML is on properties file. But it will take the path from the Catalina base. Its working fine. But when I need to execute the test case, I can not get the correct path because it will depend on Catalina base.So how can I access my XML file when Junit running?

My properties file

```
 projecthieararchy.read.derectory=/webapps/phdash/WEB-INF/config/Programs.xml
```

XML is reading from various .java files So I need to get the class path combination to the properties file.

ie. 
Test files located like this

**1. Framework --> src --> test --> delegate--> Test1.java**

**2. Framework --> src --> test --> delegate--> somefolder ---> Test2.java**

I can a add copy of XML to test like,
XML can be located

**Framework --> resources ---> Programs.xml**

How to add the test file path in property file??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to tell the junit runner where the base directory of the XML files is. You can configure the "work directory" for junit runner to be Catalina base:

- If you're running junit tests in an IDE, for example Eclipse. Check the configuration tabs for Junit, you'll find where to configure the work directory.
- If you're running junit tests in command line. you can do it as this:

  $cd /path/to/Catalina/base

  $ (invoke junit runner)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a test-specific properties file in `src/test/resources` that would contain the `projecthieararchy.read.derectory` with a value appropriate for the tests. e.g.

```
projecthieararchy.read.derectory=path/used/by/tests/to/Programs.xml
```

That would override the real value in the production properties - when running the tests.

Comment: Then ,it will only works on my PC? Because the file path is depend on the PC.

Comment: If the file is contained in your project, you can make it relative to the root of the project - for example: `src/main/resources/Programs.xml`. Then it would work on anybody's PC

Comment: the XML file is located in the following path.  /home/sachith/SCCheck/dashboard/framework/src/test/java/XMLResources/TestPrograms.xml  So what will be the relative path for this?